# Why do escaped characters in a remote asset filename throw a sandbox security exception?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3, cross-domain

I'm calling remote images with with a Loader and the context has checkPolicyFile=true, images load fine with urls like :

http://mydomain.com/someimage.jpg (so I know the crossdomain.xml file is properly setup)

but they fail with urls like :

http://mydomain.com/someimage%C3%BD.jpg

the only difference being escaped characters, is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Here is the error I'm seeing being thrown:
https://img.skitch.com/20110509-aryycpk5in4pn5k8jpfqksw25.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you're escaping it properly?  You should do a URL encode before.  You should also check to see if the encoded url actually works in your browser.  This has nothing to do with the security.

Comment: I also wouldn't think its a security error but the runtime error that occurs is a 'security sandbox violation': https://img.skitch.com/20110509-aryycpk5in4pn5k8jpfqksw25.jpg

Comment: After a quick search I found [this](https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FP-5580) and [this](http://forums.adobe.com/message/3241434).  Might be a bug with the 10.1 player.  Try to update to 10.2 and see if it's still there.

Comment: Updating was half the solution, the other half is I had to specify trustContent=true for the Image objects I was changing the data on.  Which is still weird that it would only require that for escaped content.